# Mocking ReturnsAsync using Moq to return 2 values

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, moq

Given a interface:

```
Task<Booking> GetBookingAsync(Guid reservationId);
```

I would mock the following like so:

```
_bookingLogic.Setup(x => x.GetBookingAsync(It.IsAny<Guid>())).ReturnsAsync(new Booking());
```

Givent the interface now changes to:

```
Task<(Booking Booking, IList<GAEvent> GaEvents)> GetBookingAsync(Guid reservationId);
```

How would this be mocked using Moq?

```
_bookingLogic.Setup(x => x.GetBookingAsync(It.IsAny<Guid>())).ReturnsAsync(?????);
```

Comment: Also first interface declaration is not valid one)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In second case result is a value tuple so you need to create one. Try:

```
.ReturnsAsync((new Booking(), (IList<GAEvent>)new List<GAEvent>()))
```